# Guess the Letter Program Not Working?

Tags: python

I'm creating a very basic "guess the letter" game. My code is below. When I run the program and enter one of the correct listed letters, it still runs the code as if it was an incorrect letter. What do I need to fix?

```
letters = ("M","K","O","W","X","S","A")

guess = input("Guess a letter: ")

while guess.lower() != letters:
    print("Incorrect!")
    input("Guess a letter: ")
    if guess.lower() == letters:
        print(guess,"is correct!")

input("Press Enter to Continue")
```

When the code is working properly, it should display something like this:

```
Guess a letter: p
Incorrect!
Guess a letter: q
Incorrect!
Guess a letter: m
M is correct!
```

Comment: But `guess` is only defined once: before the loop. `guess` won't change unless you set it to something with `guess = (...)`.

Comment: Debugging suggestion: type `"M" != letters` into the interpreter and see what you get. And why are you lowercasing the guess when everything in `letters` is uppercase?

Comment: Adding .lower() allows the user to enter their guess in either lower or uppercase, right? Just trying to make it more user friendly so guesses don't need to be uppercase.

Comment: Never mind, I see that .upper() is what I need to achieve that instead.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare the user's guess with the uppercase letters in `letters` using `guess.upper()` not `guess.lower()`. You should also compare the guessed letter using `in` rather than checking for equality with a tuple. Finally, you will need to store the user's updated guess again within the `while` statement:

```
letters = ("M","K","O","W","X","S","A")

guess = input("Guess a letter: ")

while guess.upper() not in letters:
    print("Incorrect!")
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")

print(guess,"is correct!")
input("Press Enter to Continue")
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!! This fixed my problem.